# iOS 11 CloudKit Record changes notifications not received in Single App or Guided Access Mode

Tags: ios, notifications, cloudkit, mdm, kiosk

In iOS 11, no CloudKit record change notifications are received when the app is in Single App Mode (SAM) or Guided Access Mode (GAM).

The foreground app would be receiving silent notifications just fine and updating the UI, but once I put it in GAM or SAM, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called (neither the background method nor the older foreground-only method).

I have an iOS 9 iPad in Single App Mode (SAM) that receives all the CloudKit notifications, and I remember my iOS 10 iPad also worked, so this is an iOS 11 issue.

I wonder if Apple is disabling push notifications in general if a device is in SAM or GAM?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed in the newest iOS 11.2.5 beta 4. Will wait for the GM release of 11.2.5. Thanks!